# What currently existing IT companies collaborated with Nazi Germany or Fascist Italy?

Tags: nazi-germany, italy, fascism

I am aware that IBM has designed the tabulator machines to calculate information dealing with the extermination of Jews, but are there any other currently existing corporations which have helped Nazi Germany or Fascist Italy.

Note: I am specifically interested in the corporations which have done something to help, not mearly existed on those territories during that time.

Comment: Quite a few, I would imagine. Are you after specifically IT corporations or would businesses like Siemens fit?

Comment: @Kobunite I am mostly interested in companies that currently work in computer programming, network system design, and computer hardware design. Not so much in those that are in sales of IT technologies produced by others. If Siemens have developped new technologies for use of Nazis that would fit, but if something that they produced anyhow was bought by a nazi somewhere that would not.

Comment: I rather doubt that IBM (and a fair number of other companies, German or otherwise) would have designed machinery _specifically_ for the task as stated.  In the case of tabulating machines, most were probably custom or semi-custom designed, and would have been the marketed to large businesses or governments - Nazi Germany would have been just a "regular customer".  Should answers then take this type of behavior into account?  What about technology that also ended up being sold somewhere else (either not specifically developed solely for Germany, or also marketed to them)?

Comment: The number of "IT companies" existing at 1945-05-08 is rather small, and IBM is probably the only one of them currently existing.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I appreciate your doubt, but the facts seem to point to that. The tabulator machines at the time were not computers, so one couldn't just change the software, there were hardware only. And they were programmed to calculate things like die-off rate during the route to camps per mile. Another fact that points to collusion is the fact that the machines were being updated by IBM after the extermination has began, so it wasn't the case of "we didn't know when we sold them".

Comment: What I meant was that your question currently implies that IBM had specific knowledge of the way the information was going to be used - that it was intended for exterminating Jews and other ethnic populations.  _That's_ the claim I was doubting.  I'm not disputing that IBM provided them machines, or even machines whose data could be used to help - there's a number of legitimate uses for ethnic history data, for example.  And in the case of IBM, they had subsidiaries, which are often locally controlled - and I rather doubt the main (US) company was allowed to sell them anything _during_ the war

Comment: To the best of my knowledge they were dealing with the Nazi germany onto the early 1940s (after the WWII has started) and i have already mentioned the fact that the die off rate calculation was the specific function of the tabulators. Tabulators needed to be updated with new programming, and IBM did that. To me the innocence of IBM is about as likely as the story of Hitler's diaries.

Comment: @Volodya he's trying to tell you we are talking about _numbers_, they didn't have to know what these numbers _meant_. It's not like they had an SQL database with column names, AFAIK.

Comment: Siemens was probably the most active, and, more importantly, **informed** collaborator. Siemens family actively supported Nazies from the very beginning and helped to install the to power. Siemens the company built crematoriums for extermination and user slave labour from concentration camps. Many currently existing companies were involved in war effort or were uninformed participants of crimes; Siemens is know to be an active and fully informed participant of crimes. If "corportations are people" were to be taken seriously Siemens the corportation would be executed in Nuremberg.

Comment: @Lohoris I could actually buy this, if it were not for the Nazi posters advertising the use of punch card machines to stamp out Jews. I had the image on my computer, but i cannot find it now.

Comment: I've found a fair amount of information about IBM's involvement and it sounds more like their machines were used by the Nazi's rather than designed or edited for. That said, In Dec 1941 IBM reported that they had no control over their German subsidiary, Dehomag. But as you said, you want examples other than IBM so it isn't an answer.

Comment: But, from what I have read it might be a case of plenty of companies were involved, but the majority of those had no option but to be involved as they were functionally controlled by the Nazi's at that time.

Answer (score 5):

IT didn't exist at the time, so technically the answer is zero, none.

If you mean companies that are currently IT companies, and created and sold equipment explicitly for the purpose of use in the holocaust, that'd exclude any company outside German occupied Europe, Spain, Italy, Sweden, and Switzerland, as there simply was no trade during the holocaust years with Germany from anywhere else.

Of German companies, no doubt many if not most supplied items that found their way into the bureacracies and organisations responsible. Therefore a list of German IT companies, filtered for date of establishment prior to 1945, would be a good start.
For the others it's much harder as there's no doubt no records of export to Germany during the war left, those would long ago have been destroyed because they'd be too embarrassing for the countries and companies involved to retain.

IBM and other American companies (and many around Europe) certainly traded with Germany before the war, and some of that equipment made its way into the SS, SA, Organisation Todt, Gestapo, etc. etc.. But that wasn't delivered for the purpose of being used as it ended up.
And if you count equipment captured by the Germans in their conquest of Europe, the list of companies gets even longer. Would you count the manufacturer of every train and truck used to transport people to the camps? Every tractor and farm implement used to grow the food that fed the local police forces and troops in the Netherlands, France, Denmark, and elsewhere? Every clothing manufacturer that created the uniforms for those people?
Quite obviously at some point you'd find that every company in every country that ever traded pre-1945 with any country that formed part of the Reich could be implicated. And quite a few of those (if they still exist) are today (or have today) IT companies. Think British Aerospace, Dassault, Boeing, Saab, the list goes on and on.

Comment: I think that there is a big difference between being 'implicated' and knowingly doing business with. The former is clearly not what i was after. But i am quite sceptical with "we didn't know" answer, when there are specific optimisations made to make tools more useful for extermination (an optimisation that did not exist as an "off-the-shelf product").

Comment: @Volodya and how do you make a mechanical calculator "optimised for extermination"? That's the kind of device we're talking about. It's not as if they were making software for computers with input dialogs reading "number of Jews to gas: X number of Jews to shoot: Y" or things like that.

Answer (score -1):

General Electric which was the majority shareholder in AEG was a large corporate donor to the Nazi party up to and including 1942. They also funneled laundered money through Lisbon to the Nazi regime after 1942 as royalties from their subsidiary Union Carbide.

GEC was prosecuted and convicted for this after the war.

In July 1943 the Nazis could not afford to continue development of the V2 rocket, thus privatised the project selling rights to manufacture the weapon to AEG. This German company raised capital on Wall Street to pay for Mittelwerke ostensibly as a loan to GEC for the establishment of an Osram Lamp factory in Brazil. Most of the funds were diverted from Lisbon to Switzerland where it was used to pay for the missiles which later rained down on London

Comment: Sources please?

Comment: Given that V2 development was a purely military operation, which never took place at Dora Mittelwerk, your assertion is pure nonsense. Dora Mittelwerk performed some V2 production, as well as manufacturing among other things Me262 jet fighters. It was a factory, not a research establishment.

Answer (score -3):

I saw an article about this on [www.europeanknightsproject.org](http://www.europeanknightsproject.org)   Subhas Bose had links to several firms in Austria. I will do a little research and edit my post later. This is an interesting topic certainly

Comment: Welcome to History Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: don't use conspiracy theory sites as if they were historical references.

Comment: If you don't yet have an answer, don't post one!